# Hive column having complex data structure giving null values after reading the parquet data

Tags: dataframe, hive, hiveql, cloudera-cdh

After reading the parquet data as dataframe, it looks as shown in below image:

[image: Click to see the image]

But now I want to read the parquet data using hive. I wrote the create table statement as :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test_13102019 (

        `DeviceInfo` STRUCT<
             `name`: STRING,
             `serialNumber`: STRING
        >
) 
STORED as PARQUET
LOCATION 'x/y';
```

But when I read the data using `select * from test_13102019  limit 10;`

I get result as null values.

[image: Click to see the image]

Please kindly help me with the same.

Comment: I dont see any partition info details for the same. May be that is why you are ending up having null result set. You always need to add a partition key.

Comment: How to add the partition key for the same. Lets say in this case we have 2 columns only, and they random actually. How to do it sir.

Comment: This parquet file is a single file at a particular location, I just want to read it.

Comment: Ok.. Lets try with this query while creating
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test_13102019 ( 
         '`name`' STRING,
         '`serialNumber`'  STRING
    )
LOCATION 'x/y';

Comment: I can't change the column name that not allowed for my project